# BiometricPrompt in android is not supporting exit on back button

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I am using android provided BiometricPrompt class to provide Biometric Authentication in our application it works fine but when i click on back button of phone then blank page is getting displayed. Instead I want app to be closed onclick of back button. Any pointers will be helpful.,

```
public class FingerprintLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(this, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                if (errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON) {
                    // user clicked negative button    
                } else {
                    // TODO: Called when an unrecoverable error has been encountered and the operation is complete.
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                //TODO: Called when a biometric is recognized.
                Context.Fingerprint = true;
                Intent fingerprintIntent = new Intent(FingerprintLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                fingerprintIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(fingerprintIntent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                //TODO: Called when a biometric is valid but not recognized.
            }
        });

        BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("touch to fingerprint scanner")
                .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
                .build();

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I implement based on the instructions given [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd) and [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html). The back button works fine for me: the dialog/prompt simply closes and I'm back to the Activity. Do you recognize the blank page you are seeing? perhaps you are implementing the API in a blank Activity? Try following the blog posts mentioned above and let us know how it goes.

**UPDATE: based on your edit**

Since you want to exit the Activity when the user clicks the back button, you have to handle `BiometricPrompt.ERROR_USER_CANCELED` in your code by calling `finish()`:

```
override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthenticationError -> $errorCode :: $errString")
            if (errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON) {
                loginWithPassword() 
            }else if(errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_USER_CANCELED){
                finish()
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have referred your blog and found it useful but my issue is different i am calling fingerprint activity from other activity . I added code on my question.

Comment: Thank you for your help .Appreciate it. It was long pending task Thank you so much.

Comment: If this response helps resolve your issue please upvote to accept it so other seekers know

Comment: On Jetpack Compose, with onAuthenticationError() converted to a suspending function, I couldn't call `finish()`.  Instead, I return `null` if `errorCode == ERROR_USER_CANCELED` using `continuation.resume()`.  The composable hosting the biometric prompt is able to pop correctly upon getting the `null`.

Answer (score 1):

For dismiss the Fingerprint dialog, you must call to:

> biometricPrompt.cancelAuthentication()